# Prevent users from sending new requests if the current request has not been completed

Tags: laravel, request, laravel-5.4

Is there a way in Laravel to prevent a user from making a new request if the current request has not been completed? I want to prevent users from submitting multiple requests as they may feel that the process is hanging due to slow internet connections. At the end of the day, each request will be create separate database transactions and bypass validation checks resulting in duplicate records - if the transactions are processed at the same time. Please note that the requests are not ajax requests, they are form submissions.

Comment: Why don't you just disable submitting buttons (or other opportunities) prior to page refresh after the form has been submitten once? You can use the `.submit()` event in jQuery/JavaScript.

Comment: I am using datatables editor popups for data submission and i am closing the editor on submit. However, on slow connections the users tend to redo the process over and over again creating multiple request.

Comment: Well, if you are listening for the submission event anyway, why don't you just block the user's ability to reopen the popup in some way. Just prevent him programatically from sending the request again and let him know until it's finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@D. Petrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5885062/d-petrov) has a great suggestion in the comments about disabling the submit button while the HTTP request has not returned a response. I personally like it.

However if you want another solution, you could require a token, similar to a CSRF token to identify each unique request. Than you can accept the token only the first time server sided and block all subsequent request using the same token after that.

Comment: Ended up going this route.. Once my request has been submitted and the editor closes, i disable all submit buttons and i listen for the the initial request to send a response. Once a response is sent back, i then enable the submit buttons.

I did not opt for the token option as at time (though rare cases, a user may make multiple submissions which are valid hence waiting for the first request to complete before processing the next one will ensure that the double submissions will be valid all the time. Thanks for the suggestion @D. Petrov